# Get codechanges in Eclipse (live)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to listen on codechanges in eclipse using a plugin. In the Eclipse [help-files](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_events.htm) I have found this listener:

```
IResourceChangeListener
```

But it seems to update when the file is saved, not when writing to it. Is there a posibility, to get these changes "live"?

---

EDIT: By code changes I mean, that you edit the content of a file in the eclipse editor. Basicly, waht I need is a Event caling, when you type something ;)

EDIT2: My code looks like this:

plugin.xml:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.core.resources.fileModificationValidator">
  <fileModificationValidator
        class="packages.in.project.MyFileModificationValidator">
  </fileModificationValidator>
```

MyFileModificationValidator:

```
package packages.in.project;

import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.team.FileModificationValidationContext;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.team.FileModificationValidator;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IStatus;

public class MyFileModificationValidator extends FileModificationValidator {

@Override
public IStatus validateEdit(IFile[] files, FileModificationValidationContext context) {
    System.out.println("Modified!");
    return null;
}

@Override
public IStatus validateSave(IFile file) {
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the change notification? It may be that the Java editor offers a better way of doing whatever it is that you want.

Comment: @greg-449 I want to send changes to a server ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Answer ;)

I used the IDocumentListener to
get changes in the Editor.

```
@Override
public void documentChanged(DocumentEvent event) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is a "code change"?... because your use case is not very clear, providing you are not interested in the change of the physical resource (when it´s saved)

Is a "code change" any change in memory of the content of a source file? If so, the answer is NO. I could write a program to read a file do something with the content in memory and you wouldn´t notice if I don´t provide a mechanism to do so.

In resume, all depends of who is accessing and if they provide a mechanism to notify that they are a doing a "code change", whatever that means for you. For physical resource changes, you were right that Eclipse notifies it for you and the `IResourceChangeListener` interface is the correct one to use in order to be aware of those changes.

Answer (score 0):

`IResourceChangeListener` is a good start. You can use this to detect changes to workspace resources.

You should also look into implementing `FileModificationValidator`. The file modification validator is a Team-related hook for pre-checking operations that modify the contents of files. You can implement both `validateEdit` and `validateSave`.

Comment: I dont get the Validator working :/ I get this message when saving, but nothing hapens `!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 1 2013-11-24 16:36:33.270
!MESSAGE There must be exactly 0 or 1 validator extensions defined in the fileModificationValidator extension point.`

Comment: Make sure you have registered your validator properly. see http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresAdv_hooks.htm

Comment: That looks ok. Of course, you should return a valid Status not null. Also have a look here: IWorkspace.validateEdit(...) It provides a number of additional details. http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIWorkspace.html

Comment: Added the return values, but still getting the error message. Do I have to register the vailidator somewhere else?